# Options to recover hard drive not shown in diskitil list

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

My iMac's internal drive failed so I created a bootable external drive from a macOS installer.

I used this to run diskutil list, which only shows the external drive (plus some disk images to do with the macOS installer).

It does not show the internal drive. What are my options for attempting to recover the internal drive?

Comment: What do you mean by "recover the internal drive" are you talking about the data on the drive or make it appear in in the list of devices so you can reinstall your operating system?  Furthermore, if the drive has failed, why do you expect it to be listed?

Answer (score 0):

Spinrite on a Windows PC is your best bet , if it spins and doesn’t have  “click of death” of sounds like from servo failure. It supports all file systems. ...click..click.click means RIP

Spinrite is from https://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm

You will need cable adapters.